# Boolean Function to Check Validity of Expression Recursively?

Tags: c++, parsing, recursion, boolean

I want to create a kind of parser of the form:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

bool isValid(istringstream& is)
{
  char ch;
  is.get(ch); //I know get(ch) is a good start but this is as for as I got :)
  .......
  ....
}

int main()
{
  string s;
  while(getline(cin,s))
  {
    istringstream is(s);
    cout<<(isValid(is)? "Expression OK" : "Not OK")<<endl;
  }
}
```

A boolean function that returns TRUE if the sequence of *char* is of the form "5" or "(5+3)" or "((5+3)+6)" or "(((4+2)+1)+6)" ...etc and FALSE for any other case

Basically, an expression will be considered as valid if it is either a single digit or of the form "open parenthesis-single digit-plus sign-single digit-close parenthesis"

- Valid Expression = *single digit*

  and
- Valid Expression = (*Valid Expression* + *Valid Expression*)

Given that there is no limit to the size of the above form (number of opening and closing parenthesis..etc.) I'd like to do that using recursion

Being the newbie that I am.. Thank you for any helpful input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do a recursive solution you're gonna want to read the string into a buffer first, then do something like this:

```
int expression(char* str) {
    if (*str == '(') {
        int e1 = expression(str + 1);
        if (e1 == -1 || *(str + 1 + e) != '+') {
            return -1;
        }
        int e2 = expression(str + 1 + e + 1);
        if (e2 == -1 || *(str + 1 + e + 1 + e2) != ')') {
            return -1;
        }
        return 1 + e1 + 1 + e2 + 1;
    }

    if (*str >= '0' || *str <= '9') {
        return 1;
    }

    return -1;
}

bool isvalid(char* str) {
    int e1 = expression(str);
    if (e1 < 0) {
        return false;
    }
    if (e1 == strlen(str)) {
        return true;
    }
    if (*(str + e1) != '+') {
        return false;
    }
    int e2 = expression(str + e1 + 1);
    if (e2 < 0) {
        return false;
    }
    return (e1 + 1 + e2 == strlen(str));
}
```

Basically, the expression function returns the length of the valid expression at it's argument. If it's argument begins with a parenthesis, it gets the length of the expression after that, verifies the plus after that, then verifies the closing parenthesis after the next expression. If the argument begins with a number, return 1. If something is messed up, return -1. Then using that function we can figure out whether or not the string is valid by some sums and the length of the string.

I haven't tested the function at all, but the only case this might fail in that I can think of would be excessive parenthesis: ((5)) for example.

An alternative to recursion could be some sort of lexical parsing such as this:

```
enum {
    ExpectingLeftExpression,
    ExpectingRightExpression,
    ExpectingPlus,
    ExpectingEnd,
} ParseState;

// returns true if str is valid
bool check(char* str) {
    ParseState state = ExpectingLeftExpression;

    do {
        switch (state) {
            case ExpectingLeftExpression:
                if (*str == '(') {
                } else if (*str >= '0' && *str <= '9') {
                    state = ExpectingPlus;
                } else {
                    printf("Error: Expected left hand expression.");
                    return false;
                }
            break;
            case ExpectingPlus:
                if (*str == '+') {
                    state = ExpectingRightExpression;
                } else {
                    printf("Error: Expected plus.");
                    return false;
                }
            break;
            case ExpectingRightExpression:
                if (*str == '(') {
                    state = ExpectingLeftExpression;
                } else if (*str >= '0' && *str <= '9') {
                    state = ExpectingEnd;
                } else {
                    printf("Error: Expected right hand expression.");
                    return false;
                }
            break;
        }
    } while (*(++str));

    return true;
}
```

That function's not complete at all, but you should be able to see where it's going. I think the recursion works better in this case anyways.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful input Daxnitro, although I'm trying to come up with something that will limit myself to using only the boolean function : bool isValid(istringstream& is) I mentioned in the original post, with recursion inside of it. I'll definitely have a look at your suggestion as well however..!